# how to use multilaguage in django website

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to make multi language site in django but I'm not getting any change in page content.

I'm working on django1.5 and I doing it like below,

setting.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'fr-CA'

ugettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('fr-CA', ugettext('French')),
    ('en-US', ugettext('English')),
)

LOCALE_PATHS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'locale').replace('\\','/') # zankar added
)

USE_I18N = True
```

django.po

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2013-07-09 16:05+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: settings.py:45
msgid "French"
msgstr "French"

#: settings.py:46
msgid "English"
msgstr "English"

#: templates/index.html:7
msgid "Hello Zankar"
msgstr "Bonjour Zankar"
```

My locale folder is outside of myapp.

Also I have compiled my .po file and it had created .mo file.
one thing I noticed when it creating .mo file message is in red color.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multi Language Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% load i18n %}
    <p>{% trans "Hello Zankar" %}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me which thing I'm missing
I think this code will show me hello message in french but no any change.
I don't know if I am wrong or the script is wrong as I'm new in django.

Please help me.

Comment: After access to index page, are you being redirected to /fr/ or to /en/ ?

Comment: And check, have you included `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: I've always read you should put the `{% load i18n %}` at the top of the template.  Also the `LOCALE_PATHS` setting has your locale directory inside the same directory that settings.py file is in.  Try hard-coding that path to see if it works.

Comment: i'm redirected to en and yes i have tried to put {% load i18n %} on top in my index.html. and yes i have gave path of locale folder as LOCALE_PATHS = (
 os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'locale').replace('\\','/') 
)                                                                    and also updated my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES by 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware' but no effect. is we need to create /fr/ or /en/ folders to access template files?

Comment: @Zankar well, if your are redirected to /en/, then django [has discovered](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-language-preference), that your prefered language is english and consequently you see original english version of your site. You can replace /en/ to /fr/ in your url to see french content. Also, you can put buttons in template to switch language manually.